# Qt Memory leaks after loading new QWebview Cpp Html

Tags: html, c++, qt, qwebview

I'm doing an Qt app in Cpp with frontend in html.

My problem is : Everytime i load a new html page, my app get +=5Mo.

I've tried to delete the old pages, seems to work but i still got +5m each new pages.

Here's my code :

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool myBridge::newView(QString page)
{
    QString path = "file:///C:/Users/ITIZ32/Desktop/WLC/Borne/";
    //QString path = ("file:///" + QDir::currentPath() + "/");

    if (!(page.compare("page3.html")))
        _mediaPlayer->setTimer(10000);
    else
        _mediaPlayer->setTimer(60000);

    _view->close();
    _view = nullptr;
    delete _view;
    _view = new WebView;
    _view->load(QUrl(path + page));
    _view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("bridge", this);
    _view->showFullScreen();
    _mediaPlayer->_srnsaver->timerRestart();
    return (true);
}
```

I've try a lot of things (like preload all the pages in vector) but i still don't understand how can i properly switch between my html pages, the load always give me leaks.
Have you got any tips to help me? I start being hopeless.

Some of you may see my older post about this, i'm sorry to post one more but the last didn't help me :/

Comment: By the way, why not use QWidgets?

Answer (score 0):

Check you code here

```
_view->close();
_view = nullptr;
delete _view;
```

Delete on a null pointer has no effect.

delete _view first and than set it to null.

In your case, there is no need to delete the old view, just call load(newurl) to load a webpage.